# How to edit and change all details in a created custom object?

Tags: custom-object

I Created a custom object in my developer platform , now I want to edit some of it's properties like Icon , profile permissions and ...
I just don't know how to edit all details , I only can edit name , description , some check boxes.
thanks beforehand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the other properties of a custom object like security settings is possible by using the correct parts of the Salesforce UI.

Security settings - go to Setup>Administer>Security Controls>Field Accessibility and you can set this by Object - and then by profile or by field.

To change the Icon on the custom tab go to Setup>Build>Create>Tabs and select the tab you wish to edit and select a new icon.

Comment: very clear answer

Comment: Thanks, I would recommend starting with https://trailhead.salesforce.com/ if you haven't already as this will let you learn at your own pace and is very clearly written.

Comment: I've already started with trailhead but sometimes I face some questions in a project so it takes time to read all the tailhead step by step so at this time I prefer to get help from some salesforce friends